# Need a hand recovering a MySQL InnoDB database

Tags: mysql, innodb, crash

I recently had my file server OS hard disk die completely. Of course I have the file storage on a ZFS array so that's fine, but not the OS drive. I was able to use Clonezilla to partially recover data on the OS drive, and to my surprise, I appear of been able to recover the `/var/lib/mysql` folder with all the MySQL tables.

I've put in a new temporary drive and reinstalled Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 and am trying to recover the database tables to I can use mysqldump to export them correctly. I copied the entire mysql folder, not just the tables, into the new OS's /var/lib/mysql folder hoping that will allow for an easy recovery. I appear to of been wrong.

I've read [https://serverfault.com/questions/367255/linux-mysql-is-it-safe-to-copy-mysql-db-files-with-cp-command-from-one-db-to#:~:text=frm%20file%20of%20the%20InnoDB,and%20its%20corresponding%20index%20definitions](https://serverfault.com/questions/367255/linux-mysql-is-it-safe-to-copy-mysql-db-files-with-cp-command-from-one-db-to#:%7E:text=frm%20file%20of%20the%20InnoDB,and%20its%20corresponding%20index%20definitions). and stepped through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html but even bumping `innodb_force_recovery` up to 6 I cannot get mysql to run. This is output I am getting in the error.log file:

```
2021-09-19T16:11:55.743425Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fut0lst.ic:85:addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA thread 139693132441344
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:11:55 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x55fa23f6d8f0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f0cd7895d20 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x55fa1eb14711]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x31b) [0x55fa1d7eb5bb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0) [0x7f0ce478d3c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f0ce3db618b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b) [0x7f0ce3d95859]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf4324d) [0x55fa1d50e24d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(lob::read(lob::ReadContext*, lob::ref_t, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned char*)+0xe61) [0x55fa1f0006c1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(lob::btr_copy_externally_stored_field_func(trx_t*, dict_index_t const*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned char const*, page_size_t const&, unsigned long, mem_block_info_t*)+0x11e) [0x55fa1ec73b5e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x27ba4bb) [0x55fa1ed854bb]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_sel_store_mysql_rec(unsigned char*, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned char const*, dtuple_t const*, bool, dict_index_t const*, dict_index_t const*, unsigned long const*, bool, lob::undo_vers_t*, mem_block_info_t*&)+0x356) [0x55fa1ed88686]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x3a0f) [0x55fa1ed8e02f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::index_read(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, ha_rkey_function)+0x331) [0x55fa1ec13b21]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::index_first(unsigned char*)+0x36) [0x55fa1ebdb7d6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::rnd_next(unsigned char*)+0x37) [0x55fa1ec14177]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_rnd_next(unsigned char*)+0x1ac) [0x55fa1d8f486c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::tables::DD_properties::init_cached_properties(THD*)+0x1fb) [0x55fa1e9c23db]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::tables::DD_properties::unchecked_get(THD*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Stateless_allocator<char, dd::String_type_alloc, My_free_functor> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Stateless_allocator<char, dd::String_type_alloc, My_free_functor> >*, bool*)+0x35) [0x55fa1e9c2815]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::tables::DD_properties::get(THD*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Stateless_allocator<char, dd::String_type_alloc, My_free_functor> > const&, unsigned int*, bool*)+0x45) [0x55fa1e9c2a85]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::initialize_dd_properties(THD*)+0x15d) [0x55fa1e8998ed]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::restart(THD*)+0xe0) [0x55fa1e89ce60]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2517271) [0x55fa1eae2271]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::upgrade_57::do_pre_checks_and_initialize_dd(THD*)+0xaf8) [0x55fa1eae8018]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x12dcbf6) [0x55fa1d8a7bf6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2ae589a) [0x55fa1f0b089a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x9609) [0x7f0ce4781609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f0ce3e92293]
```

I'm not a dba or a sysadmin so I'm kind of taking shots in the dark at this point. Based on the error above an anyone say if it recoverable, and if so, how?

Comment: Is that error from recovery level 6? Are you using the same MySQL version that was originally on the server? I see a mention of _dd::upgrade_57_ which looks like mysql8 is trying to access mysql5.7 files. You need to try the recovery with preferably exactly the same version, at worst only higher patch number. And it would be great if you could recover the original *my.cnf* too.

Comment: Ok I'll get mysql 5.7 installed. Unfortunately the `/etc` folder a complete loss. :( My next OS dirve is going to be on a ZFS mirror array do hopefully this will never happen again.

Comment: I've installed mysql server 5.7, and the upgrade message is gone. Here's the new error message:  ```2021-09-20T02:25:31.106138Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-09-20T02:25:31.118959Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!
2021-09-20 02:25:31 0x7f5589935740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140005357082432 in file ut0ut.cc line 921
```

Comment: First I would restore the files from the original backup, mysql8 could have changed something before the crash.

Comment: Fresh copy this evening, and moved the original mysql folder out of the way. Maybe making progress? Error in `journalctl` now: ```audit[1641924]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=1641924 comm="apparmor_parser"
mysqld[1641925]: Unable to determine if daemon is running: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.```

Comment: That just tells you the system knows it did not start - wrong error log :)

Comment: Need facepalm emoji in here.

Comment: With the fresh db files copied over I am back to t his error: ```2021-09-21T14:55:41.129031Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!
2021-09-21 14:55:41 0x7f67cc6f5740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140083788207936 in file ut0ut.cc line 921
```

Comment: it still looks like the files are from different versions, did you remove the old files before restoring the originals? or are there some files in the current datadir that are not from your backup?

Comment: Immediately after installing mysql 5.7, I moved the entire /var/lib/mysql folder to my home directory. After that I copied the entire mysql folder form the cloned drive into that location on the new OS drive. I'm going to go splunking on that drive and see if I can figure out exactly what version was installed.

Comment: I might just write this off as a loss and lesson learned. I've been looking at the Nextcloud files I have downloaded, and while I might not have all of them, it looks like I have the important ones. My next OS install will be on a ZFs array and I will be doing regular backups of the important databases to a BackBlaze bucket. Thank you so much for your time and help @jkavalik .

Comment: Unfortunately I have to agree - the files seem damaged beyond standard recovery. You might get (some) data back by forensics, but that will cost either time or money, probably a lot.